# Join two tables, retain the full structure of the first table SQL

Tags: sql, hive

I am having issues solving a similar problem and would like to see various ways to solving the problem.

This is a tableOne, contains the id of a person with their corresponding age of the person, and a list of cousins.

| id | name | cousin | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p | jacob | 4 |
| 1 | p | Mar | 4 |
| 2 | y | tyler | 10 |
| 2 | y | rash | 10 |
| 3 | l | amaos | 8 |

This is tableTwo, it list all name with respective ages

| id | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p | 4 |
| 2 | y | 10 |
| 3 | l | 8 |
| 4 | g | 12 |
| 5 | jacob | 16 |
| 6 | Mar | 22 |
| 7 | tyler | 19 |
| 8 | rash | 17 |
| 9 | amaos | 44 |

the Resulting table I want

| id | name | cousin | age | cousinsAge |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | p | jacob | 4 | 16 |
| 1 | p | Mar | 4 | 22 |
| 2 | y | tyler | 10 | 19 |
| 2 | y | rash | 10 | 17 |
| 3 | l | amaos | 8 | 44 |

Answer (score 0):

Very strange data model.  But I think you want a join:

```
select t1.*, t2.age as cousin_age
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.cousin = t2.name;
```

Having names and ages repeated across different tables seems like a bad data design.  Using names instead of ids is definitely a bad data design.  And having duplicate `id`s in a table is awkward.  Shouldn't an `id` uniquely identify each row?

Comment: For Hive however such design may be dictated with the requirements of partitioning of the data across the cluster.

Comment: yeah I thought about using ID for the cousin colum for the first table. But I tried you solution and it give all null values for the coursin's age .

Comment: @adeniran827 . . . That means that the strings don't match.  All the more reason to use numeric ids.